# How to delete (or hide) the only Git repository in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

We accidentally set up a Git repo in a new DevOps project, and now we can't delete it, because MS doesn't allow the deletion of your only git repo. This is becoming problematic because it keeps appearing on some screens and external tools, which can be confusing to users.

- We tried **disabling** the repo, but that just throws an error on some screens that are looking for it.
- We tried setting Read permission to **Deny**, but this just throws permission errors in various places.

So is there a way to completely hide the repo so that it doesn't show anywhere or actually delete it? We set up a TFVC repo and are using that instead, so we don't need the git repo.

It seems odd that MS will allow you to operate a DevOps project without a git repo, but after you create one, it will not allow you to delete it.

Comment: not sure if this is option but can you disable the Azure DevOps Repository service under project setting ? this is to actually hide it from works collaboration but not sure it still appearing on some of your works/screen.

underlying you can't delete the git when you activate it (it will create default repo) and all traceability need to be intact.

disable repo will still throw warning message but doesn't hard stop you continue , deny will throw various permission error upon the action

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. Here is what I did.

1. go to your Project Settings -> Repositories
2. Create a new repository, remember to uncheck the Add a README option
3. Delete the original repository.
4. go back to repos, it prompt you set the new repository as default.
5. now you have an empty repository.

[Here are the steps in action](https://i.ibb.co/Mfn7SFh/screenrecording.gif)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this only replaces the repo with another empty git repo. It doesn't remove or hide the new one. So I still have the same problems. What I'm looking for is a way to get back to the initial state of a new project: no Git repo exists at all. I do not believe this is possible at all without deleting the entire project and creating a new one, which will leave the new project fully operational but with no Git repo. I wish MS would allow us to revert an existing project back to that state. This is annoying.

Comment: The best solution I've been able to come up with is to rename the Git repo to "DO NOT USE!", lol. It's not ideal, but it at least alleviates some confusion among the users.

Comment: Disable the repo service in project settings, and Mark "OBSOLETE" on repo name, and remove all permissions from GIT , all these combination helps to reduce confusion. in Fact, you need the repo since it's integrate with others (work items, PR, pipeline reference and etc) and nearly impossible to just delete it.

Comment: @jedipi The provided link doesn't work.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst Just test the link. It works. It is a gif image.